# Changing game mode in Tic Tac Toe [The Odin Project]

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, tic-tac-toe, dom

I'm posting this here mostly  as I posted it [over at stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69169764/changing-game-mode-in-tic-tac-toe-the-odin-project) because the user that answered me recommended it:

I'm learning to code with **The Odin Project**. So far, I've been doing every project without any major problems: some difficulty here and there, but after some thinking I was able to solve them successfully.

Currently, I'm at the **Tic Tac Toe JavaScript project**. I've already made the game work, implementing two game modes: **VS Player 2** and **VS CPU**. Both are first selected through an *HTML* welcome window I made in order to avoid using prompts, and both run without problems. However, whenever I try to change the game mode through buttons I placed in the interface, I fail and the mode keeps the same.

For example, if I want to change from VS Player 2 mode to VS CPU mode, the score resets and the player's names change, but the game keeps running in the VS Player 2 mode. There's no console error displayed, so I'm sure this is related either to scope or logic!

I've already tried many things, including generating the HTML welcome window with *JavaScript DOM* manipulation, but I'm not able to make it work. It's been two weeks since I faced this problem and I'm still hitting a brick wall!

Here's the full *JavaScript* code:

```
//PLAYER CREATOR

const playerCreator = {
    names: [
        playerOneName = document.getElementById("player1name"),
        playerTwoName = document.getElementById("player2name"),
    ],
    scores: [
        playerOneScore = document.getElementById("playeronescore"),
        playerTwoScore = document.getElementById("playertwoscore"),
    ],
    turns: [
        playerOneTurn = "",
        playerTwoTurn = "",
    ],
    createPlayer(name) {
        return {
            name: name,
        }
    },
};

//BOARD & RULES

const gameBoard = {
    board: document.getElementsByClassName("box"),
    boxes: [
        box0 = document.getElementById("box0"),
        box1 = document.getElementById("box1"),
        box2 = document.getElementById("box2"),
        box3 = document.getElementById("box3"),
        box4 = document.getElementById("box4"),
        box5 = document.getElementById("box5"),
        box6 = document.getElementById("box6"),
        box7 = document.getElementById("box7"),
        box8 = document.getElementById("box8")
    ],
    cleanBoard() {
        for (let i = 0; i < gameBoard.board.length; i++) {
            gameBoard.board[i].innerHTML = "";
        }
    },
};

const rules = {
    turnChanger() {
        if (playerCreator.turns[0] == "" && playerCreator.turns[1] == "") {
            playerCreator.turns[0] = "ON";
            playerCreator.turns[1] = "OFF";
        }
    },
    resultPopUp(result, player) {
        let resultDivOverlay = document.createElement("div");
        resultDivOverlay.id = "resultDivOverlay";
        document.body.appendChild(resultDivOverlay);
        let resultDiv = document.createElement("div");
        resultDiv.id = "resultDiv";
        resultDivOverlay.appendChild(resultDiv);
        let resultDivTitleBar = document.createElement("div");
        resultDivTitleBar.id = "resultDivTitleBar";
        resultDiv.appendChild(resultDivTitleBar);
        let resultDivTitle = document.createElement("span");
        resultDivTitle.id = "resultDivTitle";
        resultDivTitle.innerHTML = "RESULT";
        resultDivTitleBar.appendChild(resultDivTitle);
        let resultDivContent = document.createElement("div");
        resultDivContent.id = "resultDivContent";
        resultDivContent.innerHTML = "";
        resultDiv.appendChild(resultDivContent);
        let resultOkButton = document.createElement("h3");
        resultOkButton.id = "resultOkButton";
        resultOkButton.type = "button";
        resultOkButton.innerHTML = "OK";
        resultDiv.appendChild(resultOkButton);
        resultOkButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            document.body.removeChild(resultDivOverlay);
            gameBoard.cleanBoard();
        });
        if (result === "win") {
            resultDivContent.innerHTML = player + " WINS";
        } else if (result === "draw") {
            resultDivContent.innerHTML = "DRAW";
        };
    },
    winCon() {
        if (
            //horizontal
            gameBoard.boxes[0].innerHTML == "X" && gameBoard.boxes[1].innerHTML == "X" && gameBoard.boxes[2].innerHTML == "X" ||
            gameBoard.boxes[3].innerHTML == "X" && gameBoard.boxes[4].innerHTML == "X" && gameBoard.boxes[5].innerHTML == "X" ||
            gameBoard.boxes[6].innerHTML == "X" && gameBoard.boxes[7].innerHTML == "X" && gameBoard.boxes[8].innerHTML == "X" ||
            //vertical
            gameBoard.boxes[0].innerHTML == "X" && gameBoard.boxes[3].innerHTML == "X" && gameBoard.boxes[6].innerHTML == "X" ||
            gameBoard.boxes[1].innerHTML == "X" && gameBoard.boxes[4].innerHTML == "X" && gameBoard.boxes[7].innerHTML == "X" ||
            gameBoard.boxes[2].innerHTML == "X" && gameBoard.boxes[5].innerHTML == "X" && gameBoard.boxes[8].innerHTML == "X" ||
            //diagonal
            gameBoard.boxes[0].innerHTML == "X" && gameBoard.boxes[4].innerHTML == "X" && gameBoard.boxes[8].innerHTML == "X" ||
            gameBoard.boxes[6].innerHTML == "X" && gameBoard.boxes[4].innerHTML == "X" && gameBoard.boxes[2].innerHTML == "X") {
                rules.resultPopUp("win", playerCreator.names[0].innerHTML);
                playerCreator.scores[0].innerHTML = parseInt(playerCreator.scores[0].innerHTML) + 1;
                playerCreator.turns[0] = "ON";
                playerCreator.turns[1] = "OFF";
        } else if (
            //horizontal
            //horizontal
            gameBoard.boxes[0].innerHTML == "O" && gameBoard.boxes[1].innerHTML == "O" && gameBoard.boxes[2].innerHTML == "O" ||
            gameBoard.boxes[3].innerHTML == "O" && gameBoard.boxes[4].innerHTML == "O" && gameBoard.boxes[5].innerHTML == "O" ||
            gameBoard.boxes[6].innerHTML == "O" && gameBoard.boxes[7].innerHTML == "O" && gameBoard.boxes[8].innerHTML == "O" ||
            //vertical
            gameBoard.boxes[0].innerHTML == "O" && gameBoard.boxes[3].innerHTML == "O" && gameBoard.boxes[6].innerHTML == "O" ||
            gameBoard.boxes[1].innerHTML == "O" && gameBoard.boxes[4].innerHTML == "O" && gameBoard.boxes[7].innerHTML == "O" ||
            gameBoard.boxes[2].innerHTML == "O" && gameBoard.boxes[5].innerHTML == "O" && gameBoard.boxes[8].innerHTML == "O" ||
            //diagonal
            gameBoard.boxes[0].innerHTML == "O" && gameBoard.boxes[4].innerHTML == "O" && gameBoard.boxes[8].innerHTML == "O" ||
            gameBoard.boxes[6].innerHTML == "O" && gameBoard.boxes[4].innerHTML == "O" && gameBoard.boxes[2].innerHTML == "O") {
                rules.resultPopUp("win", playerCreator.names[1].innerHTML);
                playerCreator.scores[1].innerHTML = parseInt(playerCreator.scores[1].innerHTML) + 1;
                playerCreator.turns[0] = "ON";
                playerCreator.turns[1] = "OFF";
        } else if (
            gameBoard.boxes[0].innerHTML !== "" && gameBoard.boxes[1].innerHTML !== "" && gameBoard.boxes[2].innerHTML !== "" &&
            gameBoard.boxes[3].innerHTML !== "" && gameBoard.boxes[4].innerHTML !== "" && gameBoard.boxes[5].innerHTML !== "" &&
            gameBoard.boxes[6].innerHTML !== "" && gameBoard.boxes[7].innerHTML !== "" && gameBoard.boxes[8].innerHTML !== "") {
                rules.resultPopUp("draw");
                playerCreator.turns[0] = "ON";
                playerCreator.turns[1] = "OFF";
        }
    },
}

// MOVESETS

const movements = {
    movement() {
        for (let i = 0; i < gameBoard.board.length; i++) {
            gameBoard.board[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
                if (gameBoard.board[i].innerHTML == "") {
                if (playerCreator.turns[0] == "ON" && playerCreator.turns[1] == "OFF") {
                    gameBoard.board[i].innerHTML = "X";
                        playerCreator.turns[0] = "OFF";
                        playerCreator.turns[1] = "ON";
                    } else if (playerCreator.turns[1] == "ON" && playerCreator.turns[0] == "OFF") {
                        gameBoard.board[i].innerHTML = "O";
                        playerCreator.turns[0] = "ON";
                        playerCreator.turns[1] = "OFF";
                    }
                }
            rules.winCon();    
            });
        }
    },
    vsCpuMovement() {
        function computerPlay() {
            let random = [
                gameBoard.boxes[0], gameBoard.boxes[1], gameBoard.boxes[2], gameBoard.boxes[3], gameBoard.boxes[4],
                gameBoard.boxes[5], gameBoard.boxes[6], gameBoard.boxes[7], gameBoard.boxes[8]];
            let randomBox = random[Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length)];
            if (
                gameBoard.boxes[0].innerHTML !== "" && gameBoard.boxes[1].innerHTML !== "" && gameBoard.boxes[2].innerHTML !== "" &&
                gameBoard.boxes[3].innerHTML !== "" && gameBoard.boxes[4].innerHTML !== "" && gameBoard.boxes[5].innerHTML !== "" &&
                gameBoard.boxes[6].innerHTML !== "" && gameBoard.boxes[7].innerHTML !== "" && gameBoard.boxes[8].innerHTML !== "") {
                return;
                } else if (randomBox.innerHTML == "X" || randomBox.innerHTML == "O") {
                    computerPlay();
                } else if (randomBox.innerHTML == "") {
                    randomBox.innerHTML = "O";
                }
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < gameBoard.board.length; i++) {
                gameBoard.board[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
                if (gameBoard.board[i].innerHTML == "") {
                    gameBoard.board[i].innerHTML = "X";               
                    computerPlay();
                } else {
                    return
                }
                rules.winCon();
            });
        }
    },
};

const modeSelector = {
    constants: [
        /* 0 */ modalOverlay = document.getElementById("modal-overlay"),
        /* 1 */ modalWindow = document.getElementById("modal-window"),
        /* 2 */ modalContent = document.getElementById("modal-content"),
        /* 3 */ gameButtons = document.getElementById("game-buttons"),
        /* 4 */ popUpVs = document.getElementById("popUpVs"),
        /* 5 */ popUpCpu = document.getElementById("popUpCpu"),     
        /* 6 */ vsPlayerTwo = document.getElementById("vsplayer2"),
        /* 7 */ vsCPU = document.getElementById("vsCPU"),
    ],
    gameMode(mode) {
        if (mode === "") {
        } else if (mode === "vsPlayerTwoMode") {
            gameBoard.cleanBoard();
            p1 = playerCreator.createPlayer();
            p1.name = playerCreator.names[0].innerHTML;
            playerCreator.scores[0].innerHTML = "0";
            p2 = playerCreator.createPlayer();
            p2.name = playerCreator.names[1].innerHTML;
            playerCreator.scores[1].innerHTML = "0";
            movements.movement();
            rules.turnChanger();
        } else if (mode === "vsCPUMode") {
            gameBoard.cleanBoard();
            p1 = playerCreator.createPlayer();
            p1.name = playerCreator.names[0].innerHTML;
            playerCreator.scores[0].innerHTML = "0";
            p2 = playerCreator.createPlayer();
            p2.name = "CPU"
            playerCreator.names[1].innerHTML = p2.name;
            playerCreator.scores[1].innerHTML = "0";
            movements.vsCpuMovement();
            rules.turnChanger();
        }
    },
    reset() {
        gameBoard.cleanBoard();
        modeSelector.gameMode("");
        playerCreator.names[0].innerHTML = "0";
        playerCreator.names[1].innerHTML = "0";
        playerCreator.scores[0].innerHTML = "0";
        playerCreator.scores[1].innerHTML = "0";
    },    
    popUpMode(mode) {
        if (mode === "popUpVsMode") {
            modeSelector.constants[2].innerHTML = "Insert Player 1 name";
        } else if (mode === "popUpCPUMode") {
            modeSelector.constants[2].innerHTML = "Insert Player name";
        }
        modeSelector.constants[2].style.marginLeft = "130px";
        modeSelector.constants[4].remove();
        modeSelector.constants[5].remove();
        let p1NameBar = document.createElement("input");
        p1NameBar.id = "p1NameBar";
        p1NameBar.maxLength = "6";
        modeSelector.constants[3].appendChild(p1NameBar);
        let p1NameOk = document.createElement("h2");
        p1NameOk.class = "popUpButton";
        p1NameOk.type = "button";
        p1NameOk.id = "popUpP1NameOk";
        p1NameOk.innerHTML = "OK";
        modeSelector.constants[3].appendChild(p1NameOk);
        p1NameOk.addEventListener("click", () => {
            if (mode === "popUpVsMode") {
                playerCreator.names[0].innerHTML = p1NameBar.value;
                modeSelector.constants[2].innerHTML = "Insert Player 2 name";
                modeSelector.constants[2].style.marginLeft = "130px";
                p1NameBar.remove();
                p1NameOk.remove();
                let p2NameBar = document.createElement("input");
                p2NameBar.id = "p2NameBar";
                p2NameBar.maxLength = "6";
                modeSelector.constants[3].appendChild(p2NameBar);
                let p2NameOk = document.createElement("h2");
                p2NameOk.className = "popUpButton";
                p2NameOk.type = "button";
                p2NameOk.id = "popUpP2NameOk";
                p2NameOk.innerHTML = "OK";
                modeSelector.constants[3].appendChild(p2NameOk);
                p2NameOk.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    playerCreator.names[1].innerHTML= p2NameBar.value;
                    document.body.removeChild(modalOverlay);
                    modeSelector.gameMode("vsPlayerTwoMode");                    
                });
            } else if (mode === "popUpCPUMode") {
                playerCreator.names[0].innerHTML = p1NameBar.value;
                document.body.removeChild(modalOverlay);
                modeSelector.gameMode("vsCPUMode");
            }
        });
    },
    inGameMode(mode) {
        modeSelector.reset()
        let inGameOverlay = document.createElement("div");
        inGameOverlay.id = "inGameOverlay";
        inGameOverlay.className = "modal-overlay";
        document.body.appendChild(inGameOverlay);
        let inGameWindow = document.createElement("div");
        inGameWindow.className = "modal-window";
        inGameWindow.id = "inGameWindow";
        inGameOverlay.appendChild(inGameWindow);
        let inGameTitleBar = document.createElement("div");
        inGameTitleBar.className = "modal-titlebar";
        inGameTitleBar.id = "inGameTitleBar";
        inGameWindow.appendChild(inGameTitleBar);
        let inGameTitle = document.createElement("span");
        inGameTitle.className = "modal-title";
        inGameTitle.id = "inGameTitle";
        if (mode === "VSP2") {
            inGameTitle.innerHTML = "VS Player 2 Mode";
            inGameTitle.style.marginLeft = "160px";
            inGameTitleBar.appendChild(inGameTitle);
            let inGameContent = document.createElement("div");
            inGameContent.className = "modal-content";
            inGameContent.id = "inGameContent";
            inGameContent.innerHTML = "Insert Player 1 name";
            inGameContent.style.marginLeft = "120px";
            inGameWindow.appendChild(inGameContent);
            let inGameButtons = document.createElement("div");
            inGameButtons.className = "modal-buttons";
            inGameButtons.id = "inGameButtons";
            inGameWindow.appendChild(inGameButtons);
            let inGameP1NameBar = document.createElement("input");
            inGameP1NameBar.id = "p1NameBar";
            inGameP1NameBar.maxLength = "6";
            inGameButtons.appendChild(inGameP1NameBar);
            let inGameP1NameOk = document.createElement("h2");
            inGameP1NameOk.className = "popUpButton";
            inGameP1NameOk.type = "button";
            inGameP1NameOk.id = "popUpP1NameOk";
            inGameP1NameOk.innerHTML = "OK";
            inGameButtons.appendChild(inGameP1NameOk);
            inGameP1NameOk.addEventListener("click", () => {
                playerCreator.names[0].innerHTML = inGameP1NameBar.value;
                inGameContent.innerHTML = "Insert Player 2 name";
                inGameContent.style.marginLeft = "130px";
                inGameP1NameBar.remove();
                inGameP1NameOk.remove();
                let inGameP2NameBar = document.createElement("input");
                inGameP2NameBar.id = "p2NameBar";
                inGameP2NameBar.maxLength = "6";
                inGameButtons.appendChild(inGameP2NameBar);
                let inGameP2NameOk = document.createElement("h2");
                inGameP2NameOk.className = "popUpButton";
                inGameP2NameOk.type = "button";
                inGameP2NameOk.id = "popUpP2NameOk";
                inGameP2NameOk.innerHTML = "OK";
                inGameButtons.appendChild(inGameP2NameOk);
                inGameP2NameOk.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    playerCreator.names[1].innerHTML= inGameP2NameBar.value;
                    document.body.removeChild(inGameOverlay);
                    modeSelector.gameMode("vsPlayerTwoMode");
                })
            });
        } else if (mode === "VSCPU") {
            inGameTitle.innerHTML = "VS CPU Mode";
            inGameTitle.style.marginLeft = "210px";
            inGameTitleBar.appendChild(inGameTitle);
            let inGameContent = document.createElement("div");
            inGameContent.className = "modal-content";
            inGameContent.id = "inGameContent";
            inGameContent.innerHTML = "Insert Player 1 name";
            inGameContent.style.marginLeft = "120px";
            inGameWindow.appendChild(inGameContent);
            let inGameButtons = document.createElement("div");
            inGameButtons.className = "modal-buttons";
            inGameButtons.id = "inGameButtons";
            inGameWindow.appendChild(inGameButtons);
            let inGameP1NameBar = document.createElement("input");
            inGameP1NameBar.id = "p1NameBar";
            inGameP1NameBar.maxLength = "6";
            inGameButtons.appendChild(inGameP1NameBar);
            let inGameP1NameOk = document.createElement("h2");
            inGameP1NameOk.className = "popUpButton";
            inGameP1NameOk.type = "button";
            inGameP1NameOk.id = "popUpP1NameOk";
            inGameP1NameOk.innerHTML = "OK";
            inGameButtons.appendChild(inGameP1NameOk);
            inGameP1NameOk.addEventListener("click", () => {
                playerCreator.names[0].innerHTML = inGameP1NameBar.value;
                document.body.removeChild(inGameOverlay);
                modeSelector.gameMode("vsCPUMode");
            });    
        }
        let inGameInfo = document.createElement("div");
        inGameInfo.id = "modal-info";
        inGameInfo.innerHTML = "You can reset the game mode during the match by clicking on any of the buttons to the right";
        inGameWindow.appendChild(inGameInfo);
    },    
};

//BUTTONS


popUpVs.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modeSelector.popUpMode("popUpVsMode");
});
popUpCpu.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modeSelector.popUpMode("popUpCPUMode");
});
vsPlayerTwo.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modeSelector.inGameMode("VSP2");    
});
vsCPU.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modeSelector.inGameMode("VSCPU");
});
```

Also the full thing at **GitHub**:

https://github.com/roznerx/tic_tac_toe

Any guidance or help you can provide is fully appreciated. Also, I'm sure the code could use a re-hash: I'm not completely sold on the idea of storing every method inside objects, but that's what The Odin Project suggests (though I'm not sure I am doing it the right way).

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: Before you post the question here make sure it works as expected. That would mean implementing the suggestions from the answer on stack overflow.

Comment: @TobySpeight and pacmaninbw : thank you for your polite answer! I'm sorry for having posted something that is innapropiate for this site.